# Output in C++ problems

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    int c;
    c = a+ a++;
    cout<<"c = a + a++ : "<<c<<" = "<<a<<" + "<<a++;
}
```

How my code come out as : c = a + a++ : 11 = 7 + 6
Why my a is automatically added 2?

Comment: What are you even trying to do? Or what do you expect from your code?

Comment: Unsequenced operations.  q.v. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Answer (score 5):

`a + a++` is not well defined.  The compiler can evaluate the arguments in either order:  left `a` first, then right `a++`; or vice-versa.  Since evaluating one has a side effect of changing the other, two answers are both "correct".  The standard says doing this is *undefined*, so you could get even crazier results due to the optimizer.

On the other hand, the `<<` operator (as of C++17 IIRC) guarantees left-to-right evaluation of the arguments.

The difference between using `+` and `<<` is [an example in cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#Undefined_behavior) in fact.

And, of course, the value of `a` has already been incremented by the first statement.  The `cout` statement will not show the same values that were used by the computation of `c`.

Comment: For example evaluation order on MSCV results in output 10=6+6